# Mixpanel flush events before app close swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, mixpanel

i'm setting `Mixpanel.initialize(token: "xxxx", launchOptions: nil, flushInterval: 10.0, instanceName: "xxx")`  here 10 is my mixpanel flush interval. In android there is and option to flush all mixpanel events  `onDestroy` method using `mMixpanel.flush()`. Is there any method to flush mixpanel events in ios on `applicationWillTerminate` method

Answer (score 0):

IN Switf  following method used to flush Mixpanel

**open class func removeInstance(name: String)**

or refer below link.

https://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-swift/Classes/Mixpanel.html#/s:8MixpanelAAC14removeInstanceySS4name_tFZ

Comment: is it to destroy instance or to send all left over events.

Comment: yeas its destroyed

Comment: ok. i'm looking to push all the left over events of mixpanel. Not to destroy instance.

Comment: Hey i'm saying what u provided is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS with Swift/Objective-C you can use two methods of the AppDelegate lifecycle:

1. When the application passes from Foreground to Background

   applicationDidEnterBackground(_ :){}
2. When the application passes from Foreground to inactive (Terminated by the user)

   applicationWillTerminate(_ :){}

And within these methods you would call the Mixpanel flush

```
Mixpanel.mainInstance().flush();//example with Swift
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate?hl=et) you can document how the life cycle of the AppDelegate class works in iOS, which in Android is like the Application class

Regards!